# Wait for firestore collection.get() onSuccessListener

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a loop which reads each firestore document in a collection and appends it as an object to an arrayList

```kotlin
var myArrayList: ArrayList<MyClass>
myArrayList = arrayListOf()

db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
db.collection("myCollectionName")
   .get()
   .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
      for (document in result) {
         myArrayList.add(document.toObject(MyClass::class.java))
      }
   }
```

However, the listener seems to be asynchronous and all the code runs through while arrayList is still empty.
How to wait for the listener to complete, and then resume the function?

Comment: call your function in **.addOnSuccessListener** so it executes after data is received.

Comment: @Sajeel I thought about it but it's impossible since everything is in a loop

Comment: Firebase API is asynchronous. So please check the duplicate to see how can you solve this using a callback. You might also be interested in reading this article, [How to read data from Cloud Firestore using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953).